# How to count hits greater than X in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Not sure why I can't think this through; perhaps its the upcoming weekend!

I have my users table:

```
user | hits
mike | 20
jim  | 30
bob  | 9
```

And what I want to do is count the number of users who have a hit count of greater than 10.  Using the example table above, the output would be 2 users (mike and jim).

Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT([user])
FROM
    [table]
WHERE
    hits > 10
GROUP BY
    [user]
```

Comment: I need a drink. For some reason, I was doing an IIF statement within the select.  My head is going to explode.  Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely trivial.

Start with `select count(*) from users` to count the number of records, and then add the condition.

Comment: Thanks.  It's been one of those days.